# @ApiMethod's complex path routing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there any ability to use Endpoint's path parameter in manner of [JAX-RS](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings)

Tried to use the same approach:

```
@ApiMethod(name="get.regex", httpMethod=HttpMethod.GET, path="{var:.*}/stuff")
public Book getRegEx(@Named("var") String sections) {
    return new Book();
}
```

but it causes

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while processing method {var:.*}/stuff in API test VERSION v1

Error while processing method {var:.*}/stuff in API test VERSION v1
```

I need this for implementing relational navigation like:

```
http://api.example.com/section1/section2/.../section_N
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's all you can do with @Named annoation (at least all what's exposed). https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types
Do you have a limited number of sections? If so you could create an endpoint for each of the cases.

You could also redesign your architecture. Are you using relational navigation for your Api, or is it a website/front-end hosted under App Engine?

Cheers

Comment: Hello Jose, actually I already redesigned my API structure, I have to reject this idea with relational navigation. Answering to your questions 1) Number of sections is indeterminate 2) All stuff is about API, I didn't planning any frontend.
Thanks.

Comment: Glad if redesigning sorted it out. I'm curious about a use case of indeterminate URIs for an Api. What was your case?

Comment: That was store with lots of sub-departments and problem was that number of this nestings ideterminate as I said above. But actually I was searching for solution only because of beauty. Finally designed with statically defined routs.